# 2001 Honda Odyssey V6 timing marks

Tags: honda, timing-belt

I'm doing a timing belt and set the crank to the mark and the front cam sprocket to the mark but the back cam shaft sprocket is not on the mark. The van was running before. Is this possible or did it move somehow?[image][image][image]

Comment: How far off is it? Is it not running now? The rear cam sprocket can move when the belt isn’t installed correctly. Installing the tensioner pulls the sprocket towards the firewall when there’s not enough slack on the tension side of the belt.

Comment: its a good 6 or 7 teeth off and when i set the back 1 on the mark it cranks but its not right, but when i set it  where i marked it before the belt was took off it wont even hit

Comment: I’d set everything to the factory marks and make sure they still line up after spinning the engine. If you can, provide pictures of where the cam sprockets are in relation to the factory marks at tdc.

Comment: ok i will tomorrow thanks so much for your response, i wiil try again and  will let you know tomorrow

Comment: The last pic is set on the factory mark but the other mark is where I was sure it was when i took the belt off

Comment: I set to factory marks and it cranked eventually but wasnt running right and spun over funny

Comment: On the rear cam sprocket on one of the spokes there should be a groove and it should be inline with the upper timing mark. 90 degrees from the mark on the side shown. If thats ok and the front cam is in alignment you may want to check compression and the valves.

Comment: i got all the factory marks lined up but it not running to good.It ran fine before i started daily driver

Comment: Take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/dS4Ykw9ysP4) and see if it helps. I'm wondering if you have the front cam off. You can also read [this article I wrote](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-timing-belt-water-pump-and-thermostat-423929) on doing this job on a J-series Honda V6 engine (which you have). Also, it appears you've put two different pictures of the rear cam gear in your question. The front one doesn't have a ridge around the forward edge of the gear (it's used to keep the belt in alignment and you only need one to do that).

Comment: the 1st pic of the back pulley is showing its ligned up with factory mark and the mark to the right is where it was before starting job,the 2nd pic of back pulley is just showing i have it lined up with the factory groove and mark

Comment: thats the video i went by but when i saw that my marks were not lined up only the crank and front pully was on the mark and the back was off.the van ran good before i started this and drove everyday but it was way past due for a belt and water pump